# How to handle deployment of several feature branches on one environment?

Tags: git, server, infrastructure, feature-branch

The feature branching approach, described here: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ is great. We want to follow it.

We have production, qa, staging, integration and local environments. Our project is kind of standard website, with PHP backend that exposes API, and AngularJS client, that consumes the API. Our infrastructure architecture is not *super simple*. We have Varnish, Nginx, Apache2, memcache, proxies, some custom middleware, mysql, elasticsearch and more. Code from our repos doesn't change the infrastructure, it's just applications' code in GitHub.

We usually work on 3, 4 feature branches at the same time.

Is it good approach to try to have all feature branches deployed to one environment, and just add one more Nginx/Apache2 vhost, add one more db schema, to the same server etc?

We could have 3, 4 separate environments for those feature branches, but I'm looking for a solution, to have it done dynamically on one environment. Should chef/puppet deploy new server configuration (vhosts, db schema etc), named after feature branch after a hook coming from GitHub?

Any other approaches?

Comment: It would be helpful to let us know, if your git project is just an application project or a configuration project (e.g. Puppet). Contains a feature only application functionality or configuration changes for the infrastructure?

Comment: Thanks, I have update the question. Hooks that I mentioned would be coming from repos that contain simple PHP, JavaScript applications - not infrastructure configuration (which we store in the chef-server).